# Why Reflexivity, Totality, and Antisymmetry imply Transitivity?

Tags: relations, order-theory

I am really sorry for my mistake. It should be "imply Transitivity" instead of "imply Reflectivity". Thank you, everyone.

I am reading Khovanov's lecture notes for representation theory of finite groups, and get confused.

He defines total order this way.

A *totally ordered set* $T$ is a set together with a binary relation $≤$ which is *reflexive* and *antisymmetric* and such that, for all $a$ and $b$ in $T$, either $a ≤ b$ or $b ≤ a$ (this property is called *totality*). In this case, the binary relation is called a *total order* on the set $T$.

Then he remarked:
One can check that *antisymmetry* and *totality* imply *reflexivity*. Thus,
a *totally ordered set* is equivalent to a *partially ordered set* in which the binary relation is *total*.

I understand why that totality implies reflexivity, but I can not get why Reflexivity, Totaility, and Antisymmetry imply Transitivity?

Here the link of the note. The remark is on the bottom of page1.
https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/ff34/cedfbc36821d57def15b59d13f2926bf385e.pdf

Comment: Read your title again. It doesn't make much sense...

Comment: @AsafKaragila Isn't this what Khovanov implies?

Comment: I don't know. I never read the book, or heard about the book. Or seen the book. but your question, as written, is just... odd.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "Reflexivity, Totaility, and Antisymmetry imply Reflexivity" - certainly reflexivity implies reflexivity so this seems trivial. What exactly are you asking here?

Comment: Well, as written this has a trivial answer, $p\land q\land r$ implies $p$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber This looks to be a followup on OP's question asked and answered yesterday ([Antisymmetry and Totality implies Reflexivity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2581235/antisymmetry-and-totality-implies-reflexivity)), but with the reflexivity condition added which makes it trivial, indeed.

Comment: If you are asking why totality implies reflexivity, note that totality implies that for any $x$ and $y$ one must have at least one of $x\preceq y$ or $y\preceq x$... this is true even in the situation that $x$ and $y$ are the same, so either $x\preceq x$ or $x\preceq x$ is true... which of course implies that $x\preceq x$ is true for each $x$.  If your hypothesis implies reflexivity, even after adding more hypotheses you will still have reflexivity is implied...  "*I understand why that totality implies reflexivity*" so hopefully nothing I said was new to you..

Comment: Lets look at another example.  Let $x$ be an integer.  The statement $x$ is even implies that $x$ is a multiple of $2$.  The statement $x$ is even and larger than 10 and less than 20 *still* implies that $x$ is a multiple of $2$ *among other things*.  Adding more hypotheses doesn't stop us from reaching certain conclusions, it just allows us to reach *more* conclusions.  That is to say, if we know $a\implies p$ is true then $a\wedge b\wedge c\implies p$ is also true.

Comment: Has anyone notice the absence of mentioning *transitivity*? Why is it missing? Is there a link to those lecture notes, so that we can see the other definitions there and try to make some sense of this?

Comment: The question devolves into making less and less sense. The remark itself is correct, yes. But now the question is *not* about the remark, so it's unclear what is the context, or where the idea that transitivity is implied follows from.

Answer (score 5):

The claim about transitivity is false. Consider $A=\{a,b,c\}$ and the relation $\{(a,b),(b,c),(c,a),(a,a),(b,b),(c,c)\}$.

This relation is reflexive on $A$, obviously. It is also total, since every two elements are comparable. It's even antisymmetric. But it is not transitive, since $(a,b)$ and $(b,c)$ should imply $(a,c)$ in which case $(c,a)$ would imply $a=c$.

---

But the notes make no such remark. The notes simply remark that totality (and antisymmetry) imply reflexivity. But this is an easy observation, since given $a=b$, either $a\leq b$ or $b\leq a$, which in both cases we get $a\leq a$. The remark then continues, a totally ordered set *is* a **partially ordered set which is also total**. The two parts of the remark are somewhat independent and I would daresay it is even [pedagogically] wrong to put them so close to each other, as it can be misleading to the unsuspecting reader.

However, having written notes before, I can also attest that sometimes you write notes that don't make full sense, because you made some observation to yourself, and didn't sit down to chase its details in completeness. This leads to many of these small remarks that can be either misleading at best, or completely mistaken at worse cases.